# Bypassing popup blocker on iOS Safari / any mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, mobile, web-applications

I'm trying to get my web app to open another page (it's triggered by a button click but needs to do some other processing first).

It works everywhere on my desktop. On mobile Chrome, it blocks it as a popup and lets me know that it did so. On mobile Safari, it doesn't even tell me that a popup was blocked. I've tried synchronous AJAX calls like so:

```
$("#somebutton").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url:      myAppURL,
    async:    false,
    dataType: "text",
    success:  function() {
      window.open("http://google.com");
    }
  });
});
```

And opening the window more directly after the click, then changing its location later:

```
var myWindow = window.open('')
...
myWindow.location = 'http://google.com'
```

But that didn't work either (it did on desktop). I'm all out of ideas. Has anybody found a workaround for this?

Comment: I am trying to solve the same problem right now (testing on Iphone 4). So far I tried several techniques (like ```window.postMessage``` to send messages from the opener window), but none of them worked yet. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: @BausTheBig thanks. When I tried the second thing, saving the window object first, it works in my desktop but on iPhone it opens the new window and never changes the url afterwards.

Comment: Yes same for me. Because the parent window (which initiated the window.open) isn't in focus anymore and so the Javascript is blocked on Safari.

Comment: @BausTheBig if there's a way to keep the parent window in focus, that would solve the problem, right? That's what I'm looking for now

Comment: The moment you use ```window.open``` and it opens the pop-up, you'll loose the focus on the parent window. So this is not an option, I guess.

Answer (score -2):

You can try :

```
window.open("http://google.com", "_blank");
```

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution. Please [EDIT](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5419867/edit) to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead

Comment: The popup blocker will still block this.